# Firebird linked tables in Access 2010

Tags: firebird, ms-access-2010

I have multiple data sources in multiple databases that I have been tasked with correlating for business analytics.  I currently have ODBC connections to two (one Pervasive, one Firebird) that I can use successfully in Excel.  A DBA friend suggested I use Microsoft Access to create linked tables and perhaps make creating lookup tables between the data sets easier.

I've run into a problem.  Although Excel uses the ODBC connection to Firebird fine, Access can't create the linked table through the Create Linked Table dialogue.  I get the following error message:

```
ODBC--call failed

[ODBC Firebird Driver][Firebird]Dynamic SQL Error
SQL error code = -104
Token unknown - line 30, column 13
when (#-104)
```

I take this to mean that whatever query Access is using to attempt to create the linked table is failing to be interpreted correctly by the Firebird database, but I don't get to see any of the code because Access is handling it.  I seem to recall reading that Access tend to fall back to SQL query structure when it can't figure out how to talk to certain databases, but I can't find the source.

I did see a post by Max Vernon with regards to linked tables in SQL server 2008.  He suggested using `Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC Drivers`, but I have been unable to locate the driver.

I guess my question is this: Is it possible to manually configure linked tables in Access, do I need to get the OLE DB interface working (I have yet to figure out where it is to install it), or is there another method I should be exploring?

Answer (score -1):

It is very easy to connect, just configure ODBC. However, when you install Firebird Server, you must select the option to copy files to the Windows directory.